# Filter SQL Server table data query before result

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm using `SQL Server 2012` and `Entity framework 6`.

Problem is: I've got `nvarchar` strings with numbers but there are also characters like "-" and signs within the numbers I'm looking for.

Let's say I've got the value `123456-1234A` stored in a table. Is there a way to select this value without the "-" and the "A"?

I'd like to select for "1234561234" and get the value `123456-1234A` returned. Is there such filtering functionality or is the only way to clean up the database and make sure that the data is inserted the same way, same format, that you want to get out?

Thanks

Comment: Use REPLACE function to replace `-` and all non digit with empty string ''

Comment: Thank you, I might have misunderstood you but that would only help to use if I got an result to format. In this case I do not have a result yet. I only know the numbers, not the other characters at the time I'm performing my query.

Comment: So, do you want to get only the number from field? Right?

Comment: Question is a bit unclear.  First mention is to select without - and A, second mention is to select and have it include the - and A.   In either case, first recommendation would be to clean-up data, second would be to  use a projection on your EF6 linq query to return the data formatted as you wish to have it returned.

Comment: yeah you're right. It's a bit unclear. In clear, what I need is that "select *  from somecolumn where number = 1234561234" should return a row where the number is "123456-1234A".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment:

> what I need is that select * from somecolumn where number = 1234561234" should return a
>   row where the number is "123456-1234A"

First you can create a function that described [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/14/sql-server-get-numeric-value-from-alpha-numeric-string-udf-for-get-numeric-numbers-only/):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @intAlpha INT
  SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
  BEGIN
    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
      SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
    END
  END
  RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

Then try something like:

```
select * from somecolumn where dbo.udf_GetNumeric(number) = 1234561234
```

Comment: It was also possible to achieve the same result using entity framework with this: `var query = from SomeColumn in Database.SomeColumn where Table.SomeColum.Replace("-", "").Equals("1234561234")` where replace can be extended to replace more than just - ofcourse. @MegaTron

Comment: Yes, but it was not clear where you want to do filter in sql-server side or in C# side. And according to the comment `select * from somecolumn...` seems that you need filter on sql-server side